# How do I efficiently stack 2d dynamic objects towards the z axis

Tags: geometry, 2d, coordinates

Lets say I have two 10 meter radius circles and I want to put 5 1-meter radius circles on each bigger circle toward the z axis.
I want the big circles and the little circles to move arbitrarily. The big circles should be able to collide and the little circles should be able to collide.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I happen to use Java, but an algorithm/pseudo code would be fine.

More specifically; How do I transfer acceleration and rotational movements of the larger circles to the smaller circles efficiently, while allowing all of them to move dynamically. Solutions I've seen tend to get unwieldy in large numbers especially when I start thinking about objects that are more complicated than large circles, but that might just be the way it is.

Comment: So you are trying to model a physical system, like "I place this penny on this record player which is turning, and then I place a dime on top of the penny" ? Do these "disks" share some axis (like a gear shaft?) Can they overlap? Do collisions only happen in the plane? Are they massless, and really 2D (infintely thin) or is there some thickness to them?

Comment: The small circles would need to rotate around the center of the bigger circles in which they reside, if the big circle is rotating. The small circles "overlap" the big ones, but the big circles should not overlap each-other and the little circles should not overlap each-other. There is technically some mass and thickness.
You could think of the big circles as "boats" and the small circles as "sailors" (top down).
I'm not too concerned about centrifugal forces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to do some math.

Suppose we have a "boat" (as you term it) centered at x1, y1, with radius r1. A "sailor" is at x2, y2, with radius r2, such that x2 y2 is inside the bounds of the boat. If the boat rotates some angle A, and the sailor is simply co-moving with this rotating frame, then the new center position of the sailor is just going to rotate through the same angle.

```
a1 = x2 - x1; //difference between centers, x direction
b1 = y2 - y1; //in y direction
a2 = a1*cos(A) + b1*sin(A); //new difference in x direction
b2 = b1*cos(A) - a1*sin(A); //new difference in y direction

x3 = x1 + a2;  //new center position of sailor, x direction
y3 = y1 + b2;  //                               y direction
```

If that round circle (sailor) has some orientation to it, then it will have to rotate by A as well - think of an orientation on the sailor aligned with the radial vector from the boat. In the new position, after the boat has rotated through some angle A, this orientation has also rotated A, so the we should apply that rotation to the sailor as well. If the sailor is just a featureless circle then all orientations are the same and we can skip it.

Comment: So if I wanted to extend this, by say, there being a mouse in a sailors hat, all I would have to is rerun the same formula with the sailor as x1, y1 and the mouse as x2, y2 and A being the changed angle of the sailor?

Comment: Since the mouse is actually undergoing two rotations (the boat rotates, the sailor  .. uh .. moves to the bow, whatever) you have to compose both transforms. Imagine you have a "world" reference frame - one transform takes you from the world origin to the boat; the second takes you from the boat to the sailor, etc. So you have to resolve all the parent transforms to get the position of the mouse. Also you might be happier in cylindrical coords (radius, angle) if everything is a circle.

Comment: Right. I'm amazed how simple the algorithm is. I could not for the life of me get objects to move along the arc generated by the parent body's rotation (Well I could, but it was a very ugly hack.). And to think once upon a time I was pretty good at trigonometry! Oh if my poor teachers could see me now.
Thanks. I'll see if I can implement this effectively.